# Trying to have pass variables on select change action

Tags: php, jquery, duplicates

I am trying to to an on the fly database update of a select field but there can be more than one instance on the page of this field. I had this working for a single on change select field change, but with more than one I am simply passing the values for the first one.

I have in the past dealt with creating unique DOM ids for these on the page, but in this instance with a select field and using the change function I am a bit befuddled. Also most of the situations I found in searching this were not for select fields or dealing with passing variables in this way. I am fully aware this is crude and probably there is a much better way to accomplish this task.

```
$('.preferenceData').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "save_preferences.php", 
        data: {data1: $('.preferenceData').val(), data2: $('#userID').val()}, // this second data element not really needed but is passing var
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(html){
            if(html) {
                $("div#updateDisplay").replaceWith('<div id="updateDisplay">' + html + '</div>');
        }
    })
});
```

The form bit:

```
            echo '<div id="userPref"><select class="preferenceData" name="preferenceData'.$row['uid'].'">';

                $prefs = enum_select($db,'db_table_name','email_preferences');

                foreach($prefs as $pref)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$pref['value'].'-'.$data['topicid'].'-'.$row['uid'].'"'.($row['email_updates'] == $pref['value'] ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$pref['display'].'</option>';
                }

                echo '</select></div>';
```

The function it's passed to:

```
function save_preferences()
{
    if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' )
    {
        $db = new db(0);

        $vars = $_POST['data1']; 
        $data = explode("-", $vars); 

        // Update Database
        $data = $db->Exec('UPDATE km_vendors_users SET email_updates = "'.$data[0].'" WHERE vid = "'.$data[1].'" AND uid = "'.$data[2].'"');

        if($data==false)
        {   
            echo $db->log;
            //return false;
        }
        else
            echo '<img src="/images/icons/success_check_animated.gif">';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you would want `$('.preferenceData').val()` to be `$(this).val()` when setting the `data` ... also you are missing an end `}` for that `if (html) {` block.

Comment: Thank you! The bracket was just a typo here but the $(this).val() was the trick. Now I just need to apply the same issue to the update image and I am almost done. Yay! :)

Comment: When attaching an event to a class, that `$(this)` becomes a magical object for that very situation. Have fun, and good luck with the rest!

Comment: I assume you care little for the rating stuff, but if not feel free to submit it as an answer and I will vote it up obviously. Thanks again! ~ Jim

Comment: I hadn't posted it as a real solution, as I was unsure if it was the sole issue you had going on. However since you said it was working, I have posted it so you can file your question completed :)

Comment: Well technically I still have to conquer the same issue with the 'replaceWith' div as when I update either it reloads all the #updateDisplay divs where I want it only to refresh the one I am updating. But yeah other than that... it works. :D

Comment: Also you can give the `select` some `data-uid` `data-targetdivid` etc values, and you can use them in the `success` like `$(this).attr('data-targetdivid')` and such :) Lots of ways to go with how you like to place and use data with js/elements. Sometimes I spend a day just deciding if I want to use attributes, or hidden inputs, or data vals ... lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code, you are trying to pass `$('.preferenceData').val()` for `data1`, which will be fairly unexpected results (and usually not a value).

Instead you can use `$(this).val()` which refers the specific element that changed, and its value.

```
$('.preferenceData').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "save_preferences.php", 
        data: {data1: $(this).val()},
        ...etc...
    });
});
```